# Where to put a vim function

Tags: vimrc

I have created a helper function that will insert a number of blank lines and a keyboard shortcut of `T` to execute it. This way I can do something like `5T` to insert five blank lines with the cursor unchanged (it's a bit different than `5o`, though mainly to practice writing a function that I could use in files).

It looks something like this:

```
function InsertBlankLine() abort

    " a: args will give us the following by default: -- see `:h: a:var`
    "   '0': 1, '000': [], 'firstline': 109, 'lastline': 108 
    "   '0' is the number of extra arguments, '000' is the list of those extra args
    let data = a:
    call LogOutput("Data: " . string(data), "DEBUG", {'line': expand('<sflnum>'), 'func': expand('<sfile>')[9:]})

    " Access a dict value get(dict, 'value')
    let first_line = get(a:, 'firstline')

    " Insert a new line
    call LogOutput('Executing normal o', "DEBUG", {'line': expand('<sflnum>'), 'func': expand('<sfile>')[9:]})
    execute "normal! o \<C-o>S"

    " Go back to the first line
    let cmd = printf("normal! %sG", first_line)
    call LogOutput('Executing cmd: ' . cmd, "DEBUG", {'line': expand('<sflnum>'), 'func': expand('<sfile>')[9:]})
    execute cmd

    " Check if there's any text on the first line, and if there is, go to the first blank line below it.
    let first_line_text = trim(getline(first_line))
    call LogOutput('First Line text: ' . first_line_text ,"DEBUG", {'line': expand('<sflnum>'), 'func': expand('<sfile>')[9:]})
    if first_line_text != ''
        normal! j
    endif

endfunction

nnoremap T :call InsertBlankLine()<CR>
```

Where should I put this function? Here are a few things to note:

- It imports another function `LogOutput`.
- It's a bit large, so maybe I take it out of the `vimrc` (which is where it currently is)?
- My `vim` directory is at `~/.vim`. In there I have both an `autoload` and `after` and `plugin` folder.

What is the suggested practice for a function like this? (Note the function is just for me, I don't care about sharing it or making a plugin or anything -- it's quite trivial in the scope of things and more for me to practice with vimscript).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Normally, the function goes to "autoload", while "nnoremap" into either "vimrc", or "after/ftplugin".

Comment: If the mapping/command if meant to be distributed, I'd say in `{rtp}/plugin/{pluginfilename}.vim`

Comment: @LucHermitte Yes, but the OP says it's not a plugin.

Comment: Indeed. My mistake, I've missed the note at the end ^^'